# Show $f$ is constant if $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq (x-y)^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

**Problem**: Let $f$ be defined for all real $x$, and suppose that

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le (x-y)^2$$

for all real $x$ and $y$. Prove $f$ is constant.

**Source**: W. Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Chapter 5, exercise 1.

Comment: This has been asked before on the site, with roughly the same answers (based on the derivative like Potato's or on the triangular inequality like Frank's). Potato: I wonder if asking questions you answer yourself immediately is part of a Grand Plan of yours.

Comment: To be honest about my motives: writing up answers is good proofwriting practice, and occasionally someone spots an error I didn't. It's very educational.

Comment: Is this a declared goal of the site?

Comment: @did Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @MattN. Would you know any reference for the fact that it is? (*This* in my previous comment refers to *proofwriting practice*.)

Comment: @did No apparently not. But as I understand it the site is here to help people improve their mathematical skills. And proofwriting is one.

Comment: Somewhat relevant to the above comments: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-please-check-my-proof-type-of-questions-proper

Comment: @did: Perhaps someone should start a meta thread? Feel free to name me explicitly and link to my post history. I will stop if people want me to.

Comment: *ducks away* ${}{}{}$

Comment: @did I eventually find that his latest posts are probably consecutive exercises on Rudin's book.

Comment: Potato: As an aside, I note that in this stream of questions you omit any indication about what you tried, what you know, and so on, which is definitely recommended on the site. @FrankScience: Yes, this is mentioned in the questions.

Comment: @did But I don't think they're all good questions, also answering one's own question is [encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: @Frank: yes, *answering* one's own problem. Thanks for the thread (which does not seem to have precisely the present situation (posting one by one the exercises from a textbook) in mind...).

Comment: @did We are saying the same thing (PS: I find that *also* in my comment is really *although*).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a proof more elementary.

Let $c=f(0)$, we have to prove that $f(x)=c$ whenever $x\neq0$. Supposing that $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer, we have
$$\left|f\left(\frac{m+1}nx\right)-f\left(\frac mnx\right)\right|\le\left(\frac{m+1}nx-\frac mnx\right)^2=\frac{x^2}{n^2}$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(0)|
\;&=\;\left|\,\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\left(f\left(\frac{m+1}nx\right)-f\left(\frac mnx\right)\right)\,\right|\\
&\le\;\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\,\left|f\left(\frac{m+1}nx\right)-f\left(\frac mnx\right)\right|\\
&\le\;\frac{x^2}n
\end{align*}
Let $n\to\infty$, we have $|f(x)-f(0)|=0$, thus $f(x)=c$.

Answer (score 37):

For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\begin{align}
|f'(x)|
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{|h|}\\
&\le\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^2}{|h|}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $f$ is constant.

Comment: But why is $f$ differentiable?

Comment: Because the limit, which is the definition of the derivative, exists (and equals $0$).

Comment: Oh, right. The order things appeared confused me. Thanks.

Comment: This is a fantastic example of turning what might be a messy proof into something so elegant, succinct, and clear it's irresistible.  I assume this was not your first draft, but rather a rework of a rougher proof.  Could you add a bit of how you went from a rougher proof to this? E.g. imagine you started with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4601610/verify-fx-fy-leq-x-y2-implies-f-is-constant), how did you get to your proof? Interestingly, the proof begins not from the given property ($\leq (x-y)^2$), nor from the definition of derivative, but in the middle, with $|f'(x)|$.

Comment: I’m sorry, but this was the first draft. If it seems polished, it might be because I have done this type of thing many times.

Comment: How did you get the idea to start with $|f'|$? It's not a natural starting point, neither what you're given (the inequality) or what you wish to end with (the derivative).

Comment: We want to show that $f’$ is close to $0$. The cleanest way to show $f’$ is close to $0$ is to show $|f’|$ is small (this avoids having to show two inequalities).

Answer (score 14):

It suffices to show that $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. We see that the given condition implies

$$\left| \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \right| \le |x-y|.$$

So in a $\delta$-neighborhood of $x$, the quotient in definition of the derivative is less than $\delta$. So the limit is 0, and we are done.