# Suppose $u,v \in \mathbb{C}$ are in the open unit disk. Is $|u|^n - |v|^n \leq |u - v|^n$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $u,v \in \mathbb{C}$ are in the open unit disk. Is $||u|^n - |v|^n| \leq |u - v|^n$?

I want to use this property as an intermediate step for something else but I'm having trouble proving it. Intuition tells me it should be true. If $n=1$, it is simply the triangle inequality. What about for $n > 1$?

Comment: isn't this just reverse triangle inequality?

Comment: @William the power $n$ is outside on the RHS.

Comment: Generally speaking, the values of a non-constant function can't be that close together. Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164804/show-f-is-constant-if-fx-fy-leq-x-y2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $u = ( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ and $v = ( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3})$, then $|u|^2 = \frac{1}{2}$, $|v|^2 = \frac{13}{36}$ and $|u - v|^2 = \frac{1}{36}$

Comment: Thanks for this. I will have to do my proof another way.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. Take $u = \frac{1}{3}, v= \frac{1}{2}$ and n = 2. Now your inequality tells $\frac{5}{36} = |\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{4}| \leq |\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}|^2$ or $\frac{5}{36} \leq \frac{1}{36}$ which is not.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this easy counter-example.

Comment: You are welcome. Ask whatever, whenever. There is only one rule when you try to learn something: There are no stupid questions.