Proof that $f(y) - f(x)\leq (y-x)^2\implies f$ is constant
I'm currently following Spivak's Calculus and wanted to know if my intuition and proof for Problem 3-20 is true:
Suppose that $f(y) - f(x)\leq (y-x)^2$ for all $x$ and $y$. Prove that $f$ is a constant function.
Proofs for this theorem have previously been asked on the forum (for eg. here). However, the answers rely on the mean value theorem and squeeze theorem, but the problem appears in the textbook before Spivak has even defined what a limit is. So, I want to know if my proof for this is correct.
Firstly: $f(y) - f(x)\leq (y-x)^2\implies |f(y) - f(x)|\leq |y-x|^2$. This can be shown easily. Let $a,b$ be arbitary inputs. Since for all $x,y$ the theorem is true, we get the following:
$$f(b) - f(a)\leq (b-a)^2$$
$$f(a) - f(b)\leq (a - b)^2$$
Since $(a-b)^2 = (b-a)^2$, you get that $f(a) - f(b)\leq (b-a)^2$. Combined with the first inequality, this means that $|f(b) - f(a)|\leq (b-a)^2$. Since $a,b$ were arbitary inputs, it follows that for all $x,y$: $|f(y) - f(x)| \leq |y - x|^2$.
Now, my intuition for the theorem is as follows:
Intuition:
For all $x,y$ it follows that:
$$\left|\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x}\right|\leq |y - x|$$
$$|slope_{x,y}|\leq distance_{x,y}$$
The original condition was effectively saying that the for any two points $x,y$ the slope of the line crossing $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ must be less then or equal to the distance between $x,y$. Now, consider any two arbitary inputs $a,b$ on the x-axis. Suppose you break the horizontal line segment $[a,b]$ into $N$ equal sized chunks. Then, the slope between the endpoints $x_k,x_{k+1}$ of each chunk must satisfy:
$$|slope_{x_k,x_{k+1}}|\leq\frac{|b-a|}{N}$$
As $N$ gets larger, the slope between endpoints of each chunk should get smaller and smaller. Eventually, if you cut up the segment into infinitely many chunks, you should just get a flat, horizontal line. In other words, a constant function.
But of course, since a limit isn't defined, considering infinitely many chunks isn't valid. Instead, I derive a contradiction by assuming that the function is non-constant and then making "sufficiently many cuts". Here is the proof for the same:
Proof:
Suppose $f$ is not constant. Then, there exists two points $a,b$ such that $f(a)\neq f(b)$. This means that:
$$\left|\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}\right| = k > 0$$
Let $L = b - a$. Then, a "sufficient" amount of cuts would simply be a large enough $N$ such that $\frac{|L|}{N} < k$. Then, we rename $a$ as $x_1$ and $b$ as $x_{N + 1}$. Then, we can apply the original inequality to each chunk:
$$\left|\frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{\frac{L}{N}}\right|\leq\left|\frac{L}{N}\right|$$
$$\left|\frac{f(x_3) - f(x_2)}{\frac{L}{N}}\right|\leq\left|\frac{L}{N}\right|$$
Adding the two, we get:
$$\left|\frac{f(x_3) - f(x_1)}{\frac{L}{N}}\right|\leq2\left|\frac{L}{N}\right|$$
If we do this for all chunks, we will eventually get:
$$\left|\frac{f(x_{N+1}) - f(x_1)}{\frac{L}{N}}\right|\leq N\left|\frac{L}{N}\right|\implies \left|\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{\frac{L}{N}}\right|\leq \left|L\right|\implies \left|\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{L}\right|\leq \frac{\left|L\right|}{N} < k\;\text{(a contradiction)}$$

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

You could also just argue for $a<b$ that for every positive natural number $N$ we have $$\vert f(b)-f(a)\vert \leq \sum_{j=1}^N \vert f(a+(b-a)j/N)-f(a+(b-a)(j-1)/N\vert \leq \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{(b-a)^2}{N^2}=\frac{(b-a)^2}{N}.$$ Looks a tad cleaner.

Yes, this is essentially the proof by Yai0Phah in the linked dupe https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164817/399263

Isn't it easier to consider the equivalence
$f$  non-constant implies there is $x,y$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\gt (x-y)^2$ making RHS very small?
